# synthesis output sense making

Tags: fpga, hardware, synthesis

I have the following verilog code that I fed into yosys. The output doesn't seem to make sense. Can someone please clarify?

```
module test7(on, clk, reset, x);
input on, clk, reset;
output reg [3:0] x;

always @(posedge reset)
    x<=0;
endmodule
```

The synthesis output is basically to wire 4'b0000 into the a buffer, output of buffer wired to x. Basically it assigns zero to output, same as combinational logic. but my question is that should it be a latch instead? what happens to value of x before the rising edge of reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, what did you explicitly specify X to be before reset?
Does the synth result explicitly contradict that?

(Nothing, and no. All is well.)

Synth is allowed to optimise anything it wants, as long as it doesn't contradict the requested behaviour.

If you haven't tested the design in simulation, and there's an ambiguity or mistake that allows synth to delete your whole design and replace it with a "0000" output, that's exactly what it should do.

Comment: actually this question is part of my effort to use rtl to express verilog's wait and disable statement, so far I have not had much success... do you have any suggestion on how to use rtl to code behavior equivalent to the wait statement?

Comment: If you can initialise values in Verilog, initialise it to something else ( like 1) so it must change when you reset it. (And hope synth obeys initial values; they aren't required to). Or add a second signal (clk will do nicely) and force a change on a clk edge, an explore wait/disable using that.